# Limit of continuous and monotone function on infinite sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequence-of-function

Let $f$ be a continuous and decreasing function and $\{a_n\}$ sequence such that $a_n \rightarrow \infty$ and $lim_{a_{n}\rightarrow\infty} f(a_n) = a$. Then  $lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x) = a$.

I am at a loss. I tried to prove it by contradictory, but I failed so far.

Comment: Dini's theorem is about a *sequence of functions*. Here, you have only one function, so except for the decreasing and continuous nature of this function, nothing matches.  "I tried to prove it by contradictory" explain further. You must have written a bunch of statements for a start : mention these. Anything you write could be valuable to others who want to continue your answer, or point out rights and wrongs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints: There is a subsequence $a_{n_k}$ which strictly increases to $\infty$. For $a_{n_k} \leq x \leq a_{n_{k+1}}$ we have $f(a_{n_k}) \geq f(x) \geq f(a_{n_{k+1}})$. Note that $f(a_{n_k}) \to a$ and $f(a_{n_{k+1}}) \to a$. Can you finish?

Comment: Yes, thank you. Since the two "outer" limits go to $a$, then $f(x)\rightarrow a$.